# ZoomIn for Mapview

Tags: ios4, mkmapviewdelegate

Mapview should launching in zoomin mode for particular pin. how can we do that programatically. any delegate methods are there for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
MKMapView * mvMap;

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.longitude = 0;
region.center.latitude = 0;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 5;  // this is zoom level
region.span.longitudeDelta = 5;

[mvMap setRegion:region animated:NO];
[mvMap regionThatFits:region];
```